# javascript on node append multiple called functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In angular, there is an option to call $http service and append the callback for success and error:

```
$http.get(url).success (function() { do A}).error (function () { do B});
```

I would like to implement it in javascript over node, so I created new file and write the ollowing code

file1.js :

```
module.exports = 
{ 


    get: function (url) {
        //should be sync implementation
        console.log("get function");
    },

    error: function (url) {

        console.log("error function");
    },

    success: function (url) {

        console.log("success function");
    }
}
```

And from file2:

```
var global = require('./file1');
file1.get("some string")
     .success( function () { console.log("success") })
     .error( function () { console.log("success") })
```

Then I run it from grunt with `jasmine_nodejs` plugin.
But this is not working. How to define module with functions that could be appended?

Answer (score 0):

The function must return an object with other function which you can then chain. E.g. if you `get` function returns `{ foo: function() { ... } }`, then you can chain it as follows `get().foo()`.

Angular uses [`promises`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for http requests, because these are asynchronous operations.

Answer (score 0):

`$http` service is performing asynchronous operation, and the syntax is based on a concept called [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Let's take a look at your example, and turn it into Promise-based module.

```
module.exports = {
    get: function(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // Perform your operation here.
            // ...
            // After your operation, depending on the status of your object,
            // you want to call either resolve or reject.
            setTimeout(function() {
                resolve("Success!");
                // or you can call reject("Fail!");
            }, 250);
        })
    }
}
```

Now, you should be able to do this:

```
var file1 = require('./file1');
file.get("some string")
     .then( function () { console.log("success") })
     .catch( function () { console.log("error!") })
```

Remember that when you call `resolve(...)` function, it will trigger `.then` method with the parameters. Vice-versa when you call `reject(...)` it will trigger on `.catch` function.

Comment: The scenario I would like to implement is equivalent to the angular http service. I mean I would like to define 2 or more functions myself and pass a callback to handle the results arrive from the first get function (e.g. get info from the http server or something else) and other functions could be appended to this function, for example: get.func1(callback).func2(callback). func1/2/3... could be any scenario that I could decide myself based on the result of the first function. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have each function return this:

```
module.exports = {
    get: function (url) {
        //should be sync implementation
        console.log("get function");
        return this;
    },
    error: function (url) {
        console.log("error function");
        return this;
    },
    success: function (url) {
        console.log("success function");
        return this;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to chain. But I highly suggest you use a framework to do this is.

Comment: I don't think this would work, `this` in the scope of this module depends on the bounded function of the caller.